# using hibernate with mysql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, persistence

I followed this tutorial [mykong](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/quick-start-maven-hibernate-mysql-example/) in order to use hibernate with mysql.

My problem is that when I launch the program I am getting this exception **org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started"**.

So I tried to use `session.persist(Object)` and `session.flush()` instead of `session.save(Object)` and `session.getTransaction().commit()`. Now I am not getting any exception but the object is not saved in the database. logs show the request

> Hibernate: insert into stock (STOCK_CODE, STOCK_NAME) values (?, ?)

Could someone help me with this ?

```
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

        Stock stock = new Stock();

        stock.setStockCode("4715");
        stock.setStockName("GENM");

        session.persist(stock);

        session.flush();

        session.getTransaction().commit();

        session.close();
```

Comment: You need to commit the transaction as well. Flushing the session does not commit your data.

Comment: still getting the same exception

Comment: can you share where you have started the transaction and committed the transaction?

Comment: I added the code to my post, but as I said I followed the mykong basic tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to commit a transaction that you haven't even started, as you're missing

```
session.beginTransaction();
```

in your code.

As per the web site above you must start a session, then start the transaction in the session, make your edits, save the edited object into session and then commit the transaction. Your flush is also causing issues, as you flush your session before even saving or committing it.

```
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

    session.beginTransaction();
    Stock stock = new Stock();

    stock.setStockCode("4715");
    stock.setStockName("GENM");

    session.save(stock);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
```